# How should I organise my mocks?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

Before I started mocking, the way specs were organized was pretty clear to me. Here's an example of a controller and a spec for its destroy action:

controller:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController  
    def destroy
        @user = User.find(params[:id])

        if @user.destroy
            flash[:success] = "user deleted"
            redirect_to users_url
        else
            flash[:error] = "user could not be deleted"
            redirect_to users_url           
        end
    end
end
```

spec:

```
require 'spec_helper'
describe UsersController do
    let(:user){ FactoryGirl.build(:user) }

    describe '#destroy' do
        before do
            delete :destroy 
        end

        it { flash[:success].should eq "user deleted" }
    end    

end
```

However, if I wanted to stub out the destroy method, I would have to do this:

```
require 'spec_helper'
describe UsersController do
   let(:user){ FactoryGirl.build(:user) }

   it "should assign user and populate the error flash" do
       User.should_receive(:find).and_return user
       User.any_instance.should_receive(:destroy).and_return false

       delete :destroy, id: user.id

       assigns(:user).should eq user
       flash[:error].should == "user could not be deleted"
   end

   it "should assign user and populate the success flash" do
       User.should_receive(:find).and_return user
       User.any_instance.should_receive(:destroy).and_return true

       delete :destroy, id: user.id

       assigns(:user).should eq user
       flash[:success].should == "user deleted"
   end
end
```

Firstly, can I just say that this is really weird to me. I completely see the benefit of mocking, how it makes it faster and non-dependent on the validity of the `User#destroy` method **but I just find it really weird how you write the mock before the code that triggers the method. Could someone explain this? Is the idea that you write the mocks in a sort of pre-emptive fashion, ready for the expectations?**

How should I write organise the above mocks to keep it DRY? Should I use contexts like this (untested):

```
require 'spec_helper'
describe UsersController do
   shared_examples_for 'it finds the user' do
       it { assigns(:user).should eq user }
   end

   describe '#destroy' do
      context 'finds user' do
          before { User.should_receive(:find).and_return user }
          context 'deletes successfully' do
              before do
                  User.any_instance.should_receive(:destroy).and_return true
                  delete :destroy, id: user.id
              end

              it_should_behave_like 'it finds the user'
              it{ flash[:success].should eq 'user deleted' }
              it{ flash[:error].should be_nil }

          end
          context 'deletes unsuccessfully' do
              before do
                  User.any_instance.should_receive(:destroy).and_return false
                  delete :destroy, id: user.id
              end

              it_should_behave_like 'it finds the user'
              it{ flash[:success].should be_nil }
              it{ flash[:error].should eq 'user could not be deleted' }
         end
      end
   end
end
```

It's quite DRY, but I don't like the repetition of `delete :destroy, id: user.id`, and it's not too easy to read either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of

```
User.should_receive(:find).and_return user
User.any_instance.should_receive(:destroy).and_return false
```

why don't you do

```
User.stub!(find: user)
user.stub!(destroy: false)
```

it isn't good practice to add expectations on the before block, just stub them

also, as you stub User#find you don't need to give a real id to destroy, you can call destroy like this

```
delete :destroy
```

the id doesn't matter

you should rethink the names of the test, check this

```
describe '#destroy' do
  context 'finds user' do
    before { User.should_receive(:find).and_return user }
    context 'deletes successfully' do
```

the output will be

```
UsersController#destroy finds user deletes successfully
```

it doesn't sound right and also you are not testing THAT, you are testing that, if the user is deleted successfully, then the flash[:success] equals something and flash[:error] equals another thing

I would refactor it this way:

```
require 'spec_helper'
describe UsersController do
  let(:user){ FactoryGirl.build(:user) }

  describe '#destroy' do
    context 'with a valid user id' do
      it 'finds the user' do
        User.should_receive(:find).once.with(user.id).and_return(user)
        delete :destroy, user_id: user.id
        assigns(:user).should eq user
      end

      context 'when the user is found' do
        before { User.stub!(find: user) }

        context 'and the user can be destroyed' do
          before do
            user.stub!(destroy: true)
            delete :destroy
          end

          it{ flash[:success].should eq 'user deleted' }
          it{ flash[:error].should be_nil }
        end

        context 'and the user can not be destroyed' do
          before do
            user.stub!(destroy: false)
            delete :destroy
          end

          it{ flash[:success].should be_nil }
          it{ flash[:error].should eq 'user could not be deleted' }
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

now the output will be

```
UsersController#destroy with a valid user_id when the user is found and can be destroyed...
```

I think it's easier to read that way and you really explain the setup for the spec

check one more change i made, you don't really need a shared_example to find user